# ¿Es posible ejecutar el comando ln -s desde mi aplicación?

Tags: java, android

Buenas a todos. Quiero saber si es posible ejecutar el ln -s de android que se utiliza en linux para crear enlaces simbólicos, yo quiero realizar esa operación desde mi app crear un enlace simbólico a un archivo. Yo se que android tiene su método que es Os.symlink(), pero este no me sirve por el punto de que es para versiones de api 21 y yo quiero que sea compatible de partir de la 14 en adelante. Así que  decidí utilizar este enlace de linux pero no se como ejecutar comandos desde la misma aplicación android y menos este de tipo de comandos. Si saben como lograr por favor comunicármelo. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ejecutar comandos usando la clase Process de Java:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("el comando que quieras");
```

Si quieres crear un enlace simbólico puedes hacer esto:

```
String[] command = {"ln", "-s", "/ruta/al/destino", "/ruta/del/enlace"};
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

Eso debería servir. Recuerda que dependiendo donde quieras crear el enlace deberás tener permisos de root

Comment: Muchas Gracias.